# Compare API Response in JSON format with CSV, both have millions of records and the csv column names differ from the JSON Fields

Tags: java, json, csv, jackson

I have converted Json Response to Jackson Object Mapper and CSV to CSV Mapper Object. How should I compare the two? Is this the correct approach?

```java
public void test_CSVtoObject() throws KronosCoreCommonException, IOException {
    File csvFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\PayrollCSV.csv");
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema csvSchema = csvMapper
            .typedSchemaFor(PayrollExtractCSV.class)
            .withHeader()
            .withColumnSeparator(',')
            .withComments();
    MappingIterator<PayrollExtractCSV> mappingIter = csvMapper
            .readerWithTypedSchemaFor(PayrollExtractCSV.class)
            .with(csvSchema)
            .readValues(csvFile);
    List<PayrollExtractCSV> mapping = mappingIter.readAll();
}

public void test_JSONtoObject() throws KronosCoreCommonException, JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {   
    List<String> personNumberList = new ArrayList<>();
    personNumberList.add("1619889490630");
    APIResponse aggregationResponse = payRollStagingAPIObject.runAggregationAPI("T01", personNumberList);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    AggregationAPI[] aggregationAPI =  mapper.readValue(aggregationResponse.getResponseAsString(), AggregationAPI[].class);
    mapper.writeValueAsString(aggregationAPI);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the input size, you should beware of collecting all of the data to memory, which might cause OutOfMemoryException.

For both sources, you should read the data line by line while discarding old data as soon as you are done processing it.

It seems like `mappingIter.next()` will do the trick, and you can use [Jackson Streaming API](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api) for the JSON source.
You already have a `PayrollExtractCSV` class, so you can construct objects from both sources and compare them, one by one.